# How to call a jquery function from an <a> tag and pass $(this), so that jquery doesn't have to use a class or id to find the element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write efficient jquery functions, so I was wondering if there is a way to pass the element itself $(this), rather than a class or an id to jquery in order to make changes to it when is interacted with.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: You can always use $(this) to get the Jquery object for the current element.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. This is actually my first post on StackOverflow and I was impressed with the quality and quantity of the responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="myfunc()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  function myfunc() {
    $(this).css( { 'color': '#770' } );
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I guess it is pretty simple then. If you don't mind me asking, how does jquery know where the function was called from?

Comment: I do not recommend this. If you're going to put `onclick` handlers in there then you might as well give them all a class and bind to a method with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already got a reference to an element, you can pass that to the "$()" function and jQuery will do the right thing (that is, exactly what you're asking for here).

So,

```
var element = document.getElementById("something");

var $element = $(element);
```

Now there's a slight difference between the results here, and *usually* doesn't matter.  Specifically, when you use a selector to find elements with jQuery, the resulting jQuery object remembers the selector string. When you wrap jQuery around an element, however, there's no selector string to remember.

I'm pretty sure you can also pass an array of element references to "$()" and (maybe; I'd have to try it) a NodeList.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by call a jQuery function from an `<a>` tag? Do you mean run the function when it's clicked? If you apply an id to the tag, you can do something like this:

```
$("a#whateverid").click( function(event) {
    // Now you can do stuff with $(this)
});
```

That registers that function with the click event on that element. You can use whatever selector you want (like "a.someclass" if you have a bunch of links with the same class). You can bind to [a bunch of different events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

You might also want to do `event.preventDefault()` -- that'll [prevent the "normal" behavior](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) of clicking on the element (for `<a>` tags, following the link, for `<button>` tags, submitting the form, etc).

Comment: I want something like <a onclick="my_javascript_function($(this))">link</a> and then make a change on the link itself when it's clicked;

Comment: Doing it with click() events is cleaner, because 1) it puts all of your JavaScript in a single location (ideally, a separate file altogether) instead of in onclick attributes, and 2) you can write a single line of code for clicking on each of hundreds (or thousands!) of identical elements, instead of having to write one for each link.

Answer (score 0):

You do exactly that. Say if you were handling the click event for an <a>

```
$('#myLink').click(function () {
   //change the link color to pink
   $(this).css('color', '#fedfed'):
   //return false to stop the usual link behavior
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All jQuery event handlers are passed the element itself:

```
$('#aId').click(function(e) {
  // $(this) refers to <a> element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.someclass').click(function(){//code})
```

This is actually equivalent to

```
<a class='someclass' onclick='someFunc()'>Link</a>
```

It's not the same, but it's equivalent.

The first method is the recommended way to go about this. You can always access the element inside it with `$(this)`. There isn't anything inefficient about this.

You could also look into jQuery delegate : http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ This will allow you to bind events to the parent element and let you decide on what element/event combinations to act on. This has the advantage of not having to bind events to multiple functions and elements.

Comment: I understand what you are saying- but if I have to look in the DOM for a given class, in my case, it might take a long time. I have thousands of items with id's in the form of item1, item2, and so on. And instead of traversing the DOM I thought it would be better to pass "itself" to the function. I guess I could also bind an event in the beginning, but this would also require javascript to traverse the entire document.

Comment: You don't need to use a class as a selector. There are loads of selectors that don't involve a class. All you need is some kind of reference, something like a parent or wrapper location.

Comment: $("a#someid") is super, super fast, even if you have thousands of elements. All modern browsers create indexes of ids so that it doesn't actually have to scan through all of the elements to get the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/tbHzT/